# Allure TestNG - Log with attachment - Not showing image in report

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, allure

I am using:

```
<artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
```

And trying to add a log with attachment:

```
public void allure_LogWithAttachment(String folder, String name , String info) {
    allure_Log(info);
    attachScreenshot(folder, name);
}

private void attachScreenshot(String folder, String name) {
    try {
        String imagePath = "src\\ExtFiles\\screenShots\\" + folder + "\\" + name + ".png";

        // Load the screenshot file and attach it directly
        // You need to implement this part based on how you capture screenshots
        Allure.addAttachment(name, "image/png", imagePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

And in allure report the attachment doesn't appear:

Report:
[image: report image]

Open Attachment:
[image: attachment image]

How can I add a log with attachment?

- Tried to create "allure_LogWithAttachment" to use in tests
- Maybe there is a simple option via Allure @Annotation, but I need it as function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

Was able to get it with this function:

```
    public static void allure_LogAttachment(String info, String folder, String name) {
    String imagePath = "src\\ExtFiles\\screenShots\\" + folder + "\\" + name + ".png";
    Path imageFilePath = Paths.get(imagePath);

    if (Files.exists(imageFilePath) && Files.isReadable(imageFilePath)) {
        try (InputStream imageStream = new FileInputStream(imageFilePath.toFile())) {
            Allure.addAttachment(info, imageStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Image file not found or not readable.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.qameta.allure/allure-java-commons/2.15.0/io/qameta/allure/Allure.html), it seems that there's no method where you can specify an image's path.

I believe as you're specifying the content type as `image` and the actual content as a string, allure is getting confused.

You need to read your image and convert it to `bytes`, and then add it as an argument here.